# How to Shuffle List Of Qoutes In Qoutes.json In Kotlin

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, shuffle

hi i am new to kotlin and want to get shuffeled my qoutes found in asset here is my peice of code

```
private fun loadQuotesList(): Array<Quotes> {
        val inputStream = context.assets.open("quotes.json")
        val size :Int = inputStream.available() // find size of input stream
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)// define byte array and put size
        inputStream.read(buffer) // read byte array
        inputStream.close()

        val json =   String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_8) //convert bytearray to string by passing array & types

        val gson = Gson()

        return gson.fromJson(json,Array<Quotes>::class.java)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
private fun loadQuotesList(): Array<Quotes> {
...
    val result = gson.fromJson(json,Array<Quotes>::class.java)
    result.shuffle()
    return result
}
```

or even better Kotlin syntax

```
private fun loadQuotesList(): Array<Quotes> {
...
   return gson.fromJson(json,Array<Quotes>::class.java).apply { shuffle() }
}
```

Comment: okkay thats nice but i want this shuffling thing every time user opens the app because it shuffles the list only first time the user install the app when user reopens the app the same qoute he gets as first qoutes every time he reopens the app